# How to check if an image exists

Tags: image, product-attribute, product-images

having this code:

`$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'slider_img')->resize(400,300)`

how to check if the 'slider_img' exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

was easy:

`if ($_product->getSliderImg())`

UPDATE:

Found a better way to avoid any image exception using try/catch:

```
try {
  $product_img = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'header_slider_img')
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  Mage::log('Image '.$e->getMessage(), null, 'image_exception.log');
}
```

Comment: I can't, I've to wait 2 days

Comment: `if ($_product->getSliderImg() != 'no_selection')` would be more proper for first solution, as image never returns false from what I know.