# Magento2, Checking if custom image attribute exist does not work

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, image

I'm using below code to print custom image in product page. But the condition does not work. However, if I remove the condition I get the image.

```
<?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$imageUrl = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_product->getDesignerimage();
if (file_exists($imageUrl)):
echo "<div class=\"designer_img\"><img src='".$imageUrl."' /></div>";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: isset does not work, if image is not exist it shows placeholder <img src="http://url/pub/media/catalog/product">

Comment: please check with below code and let me know if you have issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534309/check-if-file-exists-before-displaying-in-magento-php http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46056/how-to-check-if-an-image-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$designImage = $_product->getDesignerimage();
if($designImage != '' && !empty($designImage)){
    $imageUrl = $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_product->getDesignerimage();
    echo "<div class=\"designer_img\"><img src='".$imageUrl."' /></div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: `! empty($designImage)` will account for `$designImage != ''` as well. While it's not hurting anything, the first conditional check is redundant.